# I'm unable to remember my old phone's passcode. I've tried just about everything I know of.

Tags: locked-out, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 and it is a typing/word password-my carrier is AT&T. This phone isn't currently activated (as in I'm currently using a different phone, an iPhone to be specific, so my account hasn't been active in a while). I don't think I had the debugging enabled. I also attempted to try "Find my Mobile" and "Android Device Manager", but these require having already downloaded and activated these or require you to be able to have access to your settings which i am unable to do. Is there a way to do a backup with it like this? or is there a way besides  paying apps or factory rest to unlock it? I have very important old scripts, photos/videos, and I don't remember if i did a backup so I would truly prefer not to have to do a factory reset. Please help!

Comment: Android Device Manager requires no special setup, but you do have to be logged into the same account you have registered on the device. If it has a working network connection (like WiFi), you should be able to set a passcode and access the device. Does it even show up in ADM?

Answer (score 0):

On TWRP Mount the system,use file manager,navigate to data/system remove all files ending with .key

Done.You got your phone unlocked.

If you like than you can try xda developers site